# Access app.config file in class library from web project

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, class-library

I have a class (myservice) in a wcf class library which accesses endpoints and appsettings from the `app.config` file in the class library. This class (myservice) is called from my controller (web project). I find it's trying to read the web.config file for the web project and not the `app.config` file. How would I access the correct file?

Besides not getting any values, I'm getting this error

> *exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe*

I'm using this in myservice-

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
var serviceModelSectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);
var clientSection = serviceModelSectionGroup.Client;
var endpoint = clientSection.Endpoints;
return new EndpointAddress(endpoint[0].Address);
```

Comment: Please include the decomposition of your components between layers and show where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` in your library. The recommended way is to have your configuration passed from the using code; if for some reasons you don't want to do that, you can use Settings mechanism that creates configuration sections without having you directly access the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. What is the Settings mechanism? I can't pass the configuration from the using code, because i'm making the call to myservice in the web project and i don't have access to myservice app.config in the web project. All I want is for myservice to use it's own app.config

Comment: I don't get you. The service you're talking about - is it service or client? If the former, why are you calling its class from controller?

Comment: so i have a wcf service which is called from a helper class. This is in the services layer. I am calling my helper class from the controller in my web layer.

Comment: Then what is the configuration you're talking of - the helper or the service?

Comment: The helper and the service are in the same layer, so the app.config applies to both

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the line

```
 var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
```

There is an overload for this call available

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(string exepath)
```

Comment: There is no exepath when running under IIS.